# Don't make work jquery function when appendTo?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two div and if I resize my page less than `768px` then my `.tFFiltre` div is moving in `.tFPopup` div..so everything is okay so far but after moving I don't want to make work my js function

for example if you click `change background` checkbox button you will see background color is chancing but if I move my div in another div than don't change background color..so I mean I don't want to make work js function

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#checkbox').change(function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
   $("body").css("background","red");
  } else {
    $("body").css("background","white");
  }
});
  
});

$(window).resize(function() {
    if ($(window).width() < 768) {
        $('.tFFiltre').appendTo('.tFPopup');
    } else {
        $('.tFFiltre').appendTo('.backFilter');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tFFiltre backFilter">
  <h1>Hi this is my filter title</h1>
  <p>and this is my article for filter</p>
  <span>and I have some elements</span>
  <button>html button</button>
  <pre>code bla bla </pre>
  <xmp>
    <html>
      <head></head>
      <body></body>
    </html>
  </xmp>
  
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox"> <label for="checkbox">change background
</div>


<div class="tFPopup">
  <h3>.tFFiltre div will be moved here </h3>
</div>
```

Comment: try by using: `$('.tFFiltre').append($('.tFPopup').html());`

Comment: I try but problem still goes on

Comment: and not work properly

Comment: console.log the .html() and see if it actually returns anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#checkbox').change(function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
   $("body").css("background","red");
  } else {
    $("body").css("background","white");
  }
});
  
});

$(window).resize(function() {

    if ($(window).width() < 768) {
     $('#checkbox').off();
        $($('.tFFiltre')).appendTo('.tFPopup');
    } else {
    $('#checkbox').off();
        $($('.tFFiltre')).appendTo('.backFilter');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tFFiltre backFilter">
  <h1>Hi this is my filter title</h1>
  <p>and this is my article for filter</p>
  <span>and I have some elements</span>
  <button>html button</button>
  <pre>code bla bla </pre>
  <xmp>
    <html>
      <head></head>
      <body></body>
    </html>
  </xmp>
  
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox"> <label for="checkbox">change background
</div>


<div class="tFPopup">
  <h3>.tFFiltre div will be moved here </h3>
</div>
```

Please check the code 
I have get the whole element and then **appendto** required position

Thanks

Comment: nothing change when I resize page less than 768px checkbox function still change body background color

Comment: check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/akit/vxmqf62d/ with the same code try opening the console and check

Comment: I guess you don't understand my question..when I resize page to 768px than don't make work checkbox function and with your example too checkbox function is working :)

Comment: yes I was talking about this exactly..and for example I have a lot of js function is there any way to make all passive ?

Comment: You can pass the class instead of id and off all those element . Hope that will solve your issue